# why will fail if do map.put before checking for solutions in solving Leetcode Two Sum using hashmap?

Tags: java

For the classical Leetcode TwoSum problem of: 
Given an array of integers, return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target.

You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice.

Example:

### Given nums = [2, 7, 11, 15], target = 9, Because nums[0] + nums[1] = 2 + 7 = 9, return [0, 1].

tried code below, it will pass test cases, but fail for submission.

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum (int[] arr, int target) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("array given is null or 
length less than 1, no two sum solutions"); 
        }
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            map.put (arr[i], i);
            int component = target -arr[i]; 
            if (map.containsKey(component) && map.get(component) != i) {
                return new int[] {i, map.get(component)};
            }
        }   
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (" no two sum solution found 
"); 
    }
}
```

While if I just move the map.put after the solution check as below, will pass, could not figure out why?

```
public class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum (int[] arr, int target) {
        if (arr == null || arr.length < 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("array given is null or 
length less than 1, no two sum solutions"); 
        }
        Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(); 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

            int component = target -arr[i]; 
            if (map.containsKey(component) && map.get(component) != i) {
                return new int[] {i, map.get(component)};
            }
            map.put (arr[i], i);
        }   
        throw new IllegalArgumentException (" no two sum solution found 
"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first snippet will fail if the array contains duplicates, and `target` is the sum of two equal array elements.

Suppose that `target == arr[i] + arr[j]` for some `i` and `j` such that `i`<`j` and `arr[i]==arr[j]`. In that case, you will first put `map.put (arr[i], i)` and then overwrite it with `map.put (arr[j], j)`. As a result, `map.containsKey(component)` will be `true` but `map.get(component) != i` will be `false`, and you will fail to return the pair of indices `i` and `j`.

Therefore, you should only add the current element to the `Map` after checking the condition.

For example, the following input will fail in the first solution and succeed in the second:

```
twoSum(new int[] {4,5,7,5},10)
```

Comment: Thank you!  so means if I use arr[i] as hashmap key, will keep overwrite the value if arr[*] if arr[*] == arr[i], even using the 2nd method when the target != sum of two duplicates. Does this mean using [i] as hashmap key is better than arr[i]?

Comment: @user9571515 that's true, but in that case it won't matter that you overwrite the value. If arr[i]+arr[k]==target for some k, arr[j]+arr[k] will be == target too, so it doesn't matter if you return i & k or j & k.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the test case [5,5,8] and target is 10;
then the test case fails if you put map`map.put (arr[i], i);` before the solution check

**for same key you are overriding the indices** in the map